# GWT RequestBuilder file download

Tags: servlets, gwt, request

I implemented servlet, that creates XLS file. I am making a request from UI (GWT, RequestBuilder). I get the response, but is it possible to get ready file (with auto "save as" dialog box)?

Should I somehow set headers or something?

Here is my code:

Request implementation

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "downloadLimitsFile");
            try {
                rb.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
                  Request response = rb.sendRequest("", new RequestCallback() {

                    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                      Window.alert("fail");
                    }

                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

                      Window.alert("file downloaded " + response.getText());
                    }
                  });
                } catch (RequestException e) {
                  Window.alert("Failed to send the request: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

My servlet implementation

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=File.xls");

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    try {

        workbook = fileExporter.prepareExcellFile();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook.write(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

It was working fine (auto file download) when I was using eg. Anchor with servlet URL, but I have to use RequestBuilder now to make a request.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible, at least you can use a third party library.

Adding the header "Content-Disposition" won't work.